# Summation over nearby observations

Tags: r, dplyr, matching

I have a large data.frame which includes the price of goods and the quantity that are sold with each price. I like to find the total quantity of goods that is sold with a price similar (within a range) to price of each row. For example for the jth observation (row) I like to find the sum of quantity of goods that are sold with price lower than Price_j+50 and higher than Price_j-50, and similarly for other observations.

I can run a for loop over observations and filter the data for each observation's price.

```
df<-data.frame(Price = runif(100)*100 , Q = runif(100)*1000)
SumQ = data.frame()
for (i in c(1:nrow(df))){
  df_filterd <- df %>% filter(Price < Price[i]+50 & Price > Price[i]-50)%>% summarize(sumQ = sum(Q))
  SumQ<-rbind(SumQ, df_filterd$sumQ) 
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have a large dataset and it takes a lot of time to run the for loop over all observations.

Answer (score 2):

You want to avoid looping and binding the results - this will be very slow.  Instead, try:

```
with(df, sapply(Price, function(x) sum(Q[Price < x+50 & Price > x-50])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with `dplyr` and `purrr` you could do

```
df %>% mutate(sumQ = map_dbl(Price,
                             ~sum(Q[Price < .+50 & Price > .-50])))

         Price          Q     sumQ
1    5.2272345 284.433416 28356.80
2   17.7292069 454.122990 35459.90
3    9.7329295 509.266254 29989.69
4   68.1042808 131.169813 41230.23
5   38.5612268 938.653962 45227.63
6   44.5808938 774.296761 47758.30
...
```